# Using the MapElementClick Event to control a specific map element C#/UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps

Does anybody know how to retrieve the the properties of a mapIcon that is selected using the MapElementClick Event handler? I have multiple Icons on my map, and when I click on one of them, I need to know the Title, Location, and image that is associated with the element that I clicked on. So far I've found that the sender argument for that handler does not give any indication to which of the elements I selected. Any information or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some code on how you are handling the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you subscrible the [MapControl.MapElementClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.mapelementclick) Event, you can use the instance of [MapElementClickEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapelementclickeventargs) in this event handler argument to get event data that is from which MapElement for this event.

```cs
private void MyMapControl_MapElementClick(MapControl sender, MapElementClickEventArgs args)
{
    var elements = args.MapElements;
    foreach (var item in elements)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Tag);
    }

    MapIcon element = args.MapElements.First<MapElement>() as MapIcon;
    Debug.WriteLine(element.Title);
}
```

Otherwise, If you use the [MapElementsLayer.MapElementClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapelementslayer.mapelementclick) Event, you can use the instance of [MapElementsLayerClickEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapelementslayerclickeventargs) in this event handler argument to get event data that is from which MapElement for the event.

```
private void LandmarksLayer_MapElementClick(MapElementsLayer sender, MapElementsLayerClickEventArgs args)
{
    var elements= args.MapElements;
    foreach(var item in elements)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Tag);
    }

    MapIcon element = args.MapElements.First<MapElement>() as MapIcon;
    Debug.WriteLine(element.Title);
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you for the help!